# How to create a record at the runtime in applescript?

Tags: macos, applescript

I would like to create a variable of type record at the runtime, I found this could work:

```
set bcd to run script ("{" & "abc" & ":" & "def" & "}")
```

But it doesn't:

```
error "The variable def is not defined." number -2753
```

I would like to use this in the sub-routine, where `abc` `def` will be substituted with a variables.

How to create a record in applescript in the run-time if you have a key and a value?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
set def to "My Text"
set bcd to run script "{" & "abc:\"" & def & "\"}"
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been doing something similar recently and this is the most elegant solution I came up with:

```
set scr to "on run argList
    return {|" & dictKey & "|: (item 1 of argList)}
    end run"

set newDict to (run script scr with parameters {dictVal})
```

Hope it still helps!